# Как сделать вывод в виде лесенки на языке Swift?

Tags: swift

Здравствуйте я не так давно начал изучать язык Swift и не понимаю как сделать вывод в виде лесенки? На других ЯП это не составляло проблем. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
rowLoop: for row in 0..<8 {
columnLoop: for column in 0...row{
    if row == column {
      continue rowLoop
    }
        print(row * column, terminator: "")
        print("\n")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Немного подумав, я все же нашёл ответ на вопрос!. Всем спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа.